# react-resize-observer returns null values with Bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-resize-observer

I'm trying to detect a container size change with react-resize-observer. To do so, I have embeded a `ResizeObserver` in a custom component of mine.

It works great when the component is used in isolation. However, as soon as it is used in a Bootstrap modal (from react-bootstrap), `ResizeObserver`'s `onResize` callback is called with null values (`width === height === 0`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the way the modal is displayed: with an animation. When the modal component is first rendered, it is hidden, thus react-resize-observer reports null values.

## Instant fix

Turn the animation off:

```
<Modal
  animation={false}
>
```

At least, you should give this a try, just to make sure that fixes the issue.

## Make react-resize-observer work while keeping the animation

The trick is to start displaying `ResizeObserver` and its parent component only when the modal animation has actually started, thanks to the `onEntering` callback:

```
export const MyModal = () => {
  const [ showComponent, setShowComponent ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal
      onEntering={() => setShowComponent(true)}
    >
      {showComponent && (
        <div>
          <ResizeObserver onResize={(rect) => {...}}/>
          ...
        </div>
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
}
```